# Почему Ушинский правил Фета?

Tags: грамматика, стилистика, поэзия

Язык поэзии Афанасия Фета не раз вызывал вопросы у ревнителей строгой нормы. Известно, что редактором первой стихотворной книги Фета был И.С. Тургенев. Он так "выправил" Фета, что создал серьезные проблемы текстологам, изучающим творчество поэта, на долгие годы. Весьма характерным случаем является также исправление текста стихотворения "Ласточки пропали..."  К.Д. Ушинским. Стихотворение это было опубликовано Фетом в журнале "Современник" в 1854 году под названием "Осень" и  никогда после этого не включалось в прижизненные издания поэта. К.Д. Ушинский поместил фетовский шедевр в свой знаменитый учебник "Родное слово" (вышел в 1864 году) и навсегда сделал хрестоматийным. При этом он исправил только одну форму. Вместо формы "ЗАРЕЙ" в строках: "А вчера зарей/ Все грачи летали..."- Ушинский счел нужным поставить "С ЗАРЕЙ". Примечательно, что во всех учебных книгах для начальной школы, изданных в ХХ веке, стихотворение печатается в авторской редакции. Чем же руководствовался Ушинский, исправляя Фета, и почему правка великого русского педагога и знатока русского слова не была принята в дидактике?

Comment: Видимо, "делать что-то зарёю" (вместо "на заре" и по аналогии с "ночью", "днем") вышло из употребления и было в учебных целях адаптировано к современному языку. "С зарёю" = "с наступлением зари" - это вызывает меньше вопросов у современного читателя.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не переусердствовали с эстетизмом? Я не вижу здесь пространственного значения.  По-моему, здесь именно временное значение.

Образование наречий происходило и происходит различными путями. 
          Наиболее характерным из них является окаменение:

Отрыв одной из именных форм от системы словоизменения с одновременным переосмыслением ее на основе новой функции слова. Например, наречия летом, зимой, днем, вечером представляют собой формы творительного падежа именного склонения, застывшие в результате употребления в качестве обстоятельственного слова при глаголе (приехать летом, ложиться вечером, работать днем) (ср. : приехать ранним летом) . Просто само слово заря имеет предметное значение, поэтому нужно отличать наречие от существительного.

*Спи, ещё зарёю (утренней зарёю)*(**наречие времени**)

*Холодно и рано;*

*Звёзды за горою*

*Блещут средь тумана.(Фет)*

---

*Как мошки зарею,* (**наречие времени**)

*Крылатые звуки толпятся;*

*С любимой мечтою*

*Не хочется сердцу расстаться.(Фет)*

**Здесь то же самое:**

*Ласточки пропали,*

*А вчера зарей (вечерней зарёй)*

*Всё грачи летали*

*Да, как сеть, мелькали*

*Вон над той горой.*

А вот предложная форма ***с зарёю*** воспринимается как многозначная:

Пусть ты отблеск, пленяющий нас,

Пусть за ним ты несешься мечтою,

Но тебе наш молитвенный час,

Что слетает к нам в душу с зарею.(**вместе с зарёю** и **как только загорится заря** - хоть утренняя, хоть вечерняя)

**Беспредложная форма творит. падежа воспринимается как более старая** и чисто временная - окаменелая, потому Фет к ней и прибегает для книжности, **поэтической выразительности**. Ну вот форма вечор (вчера вечером) устаревшая, поэтическая, а вечером - уже общеупотребительная. Поэтому у Пушкина народно-поэтическое **вечор**, а у Фета **зарёй**.

Comment: Никто не спорит, что временное значение здесь преобладающее. Но "зарей", в отличие от "вечор" содержит в себе оттенок пространственной семантики. И в "Ласточках" есть  конкретный пространственный  контекст "как сеть, мелькали", "вон за той горой". Тынянов ввел понятия "единства и тесноты стихового ряда", за счет которой возникают "колеблющиеся семантические признаки".  Вторичный пространственный семантический признак  скрыто присутствующий в значении слова "зарей", активизируется за счет стихотворного контекста, оказывая воздействие на образы, возникающие  при чтении фетовского шедевра.

Answer (score 0):

Для большей наглядности привожу все четверостишье:

Ласточки пропали,
А вчера зарёй
Всё грачи летали
Да, как сеть, мелькали
Вон над той горой.

Исправляя Фета, Ушинский следовал норме, ориентируясь на существующее в русском языке словосочетание "вставать с зарей". К этому его побуждала дидактическая задача, стоящая перед учебником - научить детей правильной речи.  . Вместе с тем правка Ушинского, с одной стороны, вступает в противоречие с логикой текста (у Фета идет речь не об утренней,а о вечерней заре), а с другой — разрушает образ, возникающий в результате игры грамматических ассоциаций. Словоформа "зарей" имеет у Фета не только временное значение, несмотря на контекстную соотнесенность этой формы с наречием "вчера". Тем более, что временное значение для слова "заря" является вторичным (в отличие от слов "утро", "вечер"). Нормативно употребление лексемы с предлогами ("с зарей", "на заре" и пр.). Беспредложная же форма воспринимается,скорее, в ряду форм творительного падежа слов предметной семантики, употребляемых в обстоятельственном значении: «пространство, внутри которого совершается движение»; ср.: полем, лесом, морем, берегом (идти,плыть). Совмещение пространственного и временного категориальных значений в форме зарей дает основание рассматривать ее как грамматическую метафору, связанную с изобразительным и выразительным планами (образ стаи грачей на фоне зари и образ-переживание уходящего времени).